How to give Mozilla FF clipboard permissions in cypress
I have a cypress test that includes checking that the copy button has copied value in an input field. The issue is I haven't found a good way to give clipboard permissions for the Mozilla browser as it is possible to do with Chrome browser.
And I'm not sure if such test makes sense if instead of giving clipboard permission to a browser I simulate the copying action:
cy.document()
    .then((doc) => {
       const input = doc.querySelector(inputSelector)
       input.select()
       doc.execCommand('copy')
    })

I tried to add clipboard permission to a cypress config file
env: {
    permissions: {
      'clipboard-write': true
    }
}


You can do it this way let me know if it works.. !
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    firefoxGcInterval: null
  },
})

Then add a custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('pasteText', (text) => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    win.navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(() => {
      cy.focused().trigger('paste');
    });
  });
});

Then in your test file you can use a custom command
it('should paste text', () => {
  cy.visit('your-page-url');
  cy.get('input-selector').focus();
  cy.pasteText('Text to paste');
});

